# How would you get reference to a dm channel by just the user?

Tags: discord.js

I have a mod mail bot that went down for a few hours, so I want to fetch all the dms the bot received while it was down.

I have tried looping through all the members and checking the `.dmChannel` property but since it's cache based, it doesn't work

So the next step would be to fetch the channel, but you need the ID to do so, and I haven't found a way to get that.

I thought of using `.send()` on the members which would give me the channel object but it would probably annoy a lot of them.

So is there any other way to get reference to a user's dm channel which isn't cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`User.createDM`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createDM) to create a DM channel with them if you don't have one already:

```js
const dmchannel = await user.createDM();
```